# "global name 'range_iter_len' is not defined" when using Numba

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, numba

I was working with massive image manipulation using OpenCV and have the idea to use GPU instead of CPU to speed up the computation. I'm using [Pointillism](https://github.com/matteo-ronchetti/Pointillism) to manipulate the image and it involves quite some math, it took significant time to finish processing each image. Here's the code:

```
@jit
def toPointillismPainting(img):
    stroke_scale = int(math.ceil(max(img.shape) / 250))
    #print("Automatically chosen stroke scale: %d" % stroke_scale)
    
    gradient_smoothing_radius = int(round(max(img.shape) / 50))
    #print("Automatically chosen gradient smoothing radius: %d" % gradient_smoothing_radius)

    # convert the image to grayscale to compute the gradient
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #print("Computing color palette...")
    palette = ColorPalette.from_image(img, 20)

    #print("Extending color palette...")
    palette = palette.extend([(0, 50, 0), (15, 30, 0), (-15, 30, 0)])

    #print("Computing gradient...")
    gradient = VectorField.from_gradient(gray)

    #print("Smoothing gradient...")
    gradient.smooth(gradient_smoothing_radius)

    #print("Drawing image...")
    # create a "cartonized" version of the image to use as a base for the painting
    res = cv2.medianBlur(img, 11)
    # define a randomized grid of locations for the brush strokes
    grid = randomized_grid(img.shape[0], img.shape[1], scale=3)
    batch_size = 10000

    #bar = progressbar.ProgressBar()
    for h in range(0, len(grid), batch_size):
        # get the pixel colors at each point of the grid
        pixels = np.array([img[x[0], x[1]] for x in grid[h:min(h + batch_size, len(grid))]])
        # precompute the probabilities for each color in the palette
        # lower values of k means more randomnes
        color_probabilities = compute_color_probabilities(pixels, palette, k=9)

        for i, (y, x) in enumerate(grid[h:min(h + batch_size, len(grid))]):
            color = color_select(color_probabilities[i], palette)
            angle = math.degrees(gradient.direction(y, x)) + 90
            length = int(round(stroke_scale + stroke_scale * math.sqrt(gradient.magnitude(y, x))))

            # draw the brush stroke
            cv2.ellipse(res, (x, y), (length, stroke_scale), angle, 0, 360, color, -1, cv2.LINE_AA)

    return res
```

This returned me an error which usually didn't happen when I'm not using `@jit` decorator.

```
global name 'range_iter_len' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[projectname]", line 201, in <module>
    res = toPointillismPainting(img)
NameError: global name 'range_iter_len' is not defined
removed temporary images
```

When debugging, I realized that this `range_iter_len` variable is nowhere used in my project nor the Pointillism code itself. And I only found [a single github](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3659) issue on Numba and it doesn't seem to have similar root cause. Any help would be appreciated, and I will update any important points I missed or when I found the solution.

Comment: I would suggest working on a MRE (like, minimal, self-contained, not requiring that repository you linked) and then submitting that to numba as an issue. I think this is only solvable by those that implement numba. it _is_ a seemingly internal error coming from numba.

Comment: I have submitted the issue to numba repository, but looking at the number of current open issue it has, I doubt that it would be answered in the near future.

Comment: in the meantime you could try replacing that list comprehension

Comment: Where is line 201?

Comment: Line 201 is just that. `res = toPointillismPainting(img)`. I called the function, the parameter `img` is image handler of opencv2.